# selenide error: rg.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException

Tags: selenium

Доброе время суток!
Запуск следующего кода

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide;
import org.junit.*;

public class testJ {
@Test
public void UserCan() throws Exception {
Selenide.open("https://www.youtube.com");
}
}
```

приводит к

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException at testJ.java:8
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException at testJ.java:8
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException at testJ.java:8
```

Также есть gradle.build со след кодом

```
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile 'com.codeborne:selenide:4.7'
testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.10'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-nop', version: '1.7.13';
}
```

И доп ошибки в консоли

```
PM com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.FirefoxDriverFactory createFirefoxDriver
INFO: Firefox 48+ is currently not supported by Selenium Firefox driver. Use browser=marionette with geckodriver, when using it.
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting 45 seconds for Firefox to start.
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'USER-PC', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
selenide.url: https://www.youtube.com
selenide.baseUrl: http://localhost:8080

at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:112)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.start(XpiDriverService.java:97)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:646)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:255)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:237)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:138)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:137)
at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.FirefoxDriverFactory.createFirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverFactory.java:30)
at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.FirefoxDriverFactory.create(FirefoxDriverFactory.java:23)
at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.lambda$createWebDriver$0(WebDriverFactory.java:55)
at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:55)
at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.createDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:242)
at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:113)
at com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverRunner.java:142)
at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.Navigator.navigateToAbsoluteUrl(Navigator.java:69)
at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.Navigator.open(Navigator.java:32)
at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:79)
at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:53)
at testJ.UserCan(testJ.java:8)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:42516/hub/status] to be available after 45003 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:102)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:110)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
at
```

com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:77)
    ... 45 more
    Process finished with exit code -1

PATH выглядит вот так `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\;%MAVEN_HOME%/bin\;%GRADLE_HOME%/bin\;%GECKODRIVER%;`

Сейчас: просто запускается фаерфокс и все, потом тест падает.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы убрать эту ошибку ?
как запускать тесты в хроме? Configuration.browser = "chrome"; ? понятно, что импортом. но как и куда прописать путь к chromedriver.exe

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Так сказано же в логе:

> INFO: Firefox 48+ is currently not supported by Selenium Firefox
>   driver. Use browser=marionette with geckodriver, when using it.